# Python Maps with 3 items

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pygame

I am trying to make a game where a turtle follows your mouse, and you have to collect  a certain amount of fish before time runs out, but the fish disappear after a while.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to make the fish disappear. I thought of using a python map. The only problem is, maps can only have 2 items that correspond to each other. I want to keep track of three items, fish_count (the number of fish that have been blitted), and the x and y positions of each. I want to reference the map later to see when to make the fish disappear, and to delete them when the turtle collides with the fish.

My question is: Is there an easier way to store the information so that I can keep track of it easier and more efficiently

I AM NOT ASKING FOR A CODE DUMP!

Here is my code that I have already:

```
import math
import random
import sys
import time
from pygame import *
import pygame
pygame.init()

 #------Easy-Change Variables
mouse_visibility = False
turtlespeed = 4

 #------Fonts
font = pygame.font.SysFont("C:/Python34/TurtleFont.ttf", 48)

 #------Timer Setup
start_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

 #------Theme Music
pygame.mixer.music.load('C:/Python34/Jumpshot.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(1, 0.0)

 #------BG, Screen & Caption
pygame.display.set_caption('Fishy the Turtle')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 616))
bg_img = pygame.image.load("C:/Python34/icebackground.png")
screen.blit(bg_img,(0,0))
pygame.display.flip()

 #------Image Preparation
turtle = pygame.image.load("C:/Python34/turtle.png")
fish = pygame.image.load("C:/Python34/fish.png")

 #------Movement, Coords, Collisions & Fish
turtlepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(mouse_visibility)

fish_count = 0

if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[1] == True:
    while 1 == 1:
        mousepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        text = font.render("Points: %s" % points, True, (0, 128, 0))
        screen.blit(text, (0, 0))

        new_fish = random.randint(0, 6)
        fish_x = random.randint(0, 943)
        fish_y = random.randint(0, 552)

        if mousepos[1] - turtlepos[1] < 0:  
            turtlepos[1] -= turtlespeed
        else:
            turtlepos[1] += turtlespeed

        if mousepos[2] - turtlepos[2] < 0:
            turtlepos[2] -= turtlespeed
        else:
            turtlepos[2] += turtlespeed

        if elapsed_time == 45:
            sys.exit()
            print("Sorry! Game Over!")

        screen.blit(turtle,(turtlepos[1],turtlepos[2]))
        pygame.display.flip()

        if new_fish == 0:
            screen.blit(fish,(fish_x, fish_y)
            pygame.display.flip()
            fish_count += 1


        pygame.display.update()
        mainClock.tick(40)
```

EDIT: Full project so far:

```
import math
import random
import sys
import time
from pygame import *
import pygame
pygame.init()

 #------Easy-Change Variables
mouse_visibility = False
turtlespeed = 4

 #------Font
font = pygame.font.SysFont("C:/Python34/TurtleFont.ttf", 48)

 #------Theme Music & Sound Effects
pygame.mixer.music.load('C:/Python34/Jumpshot.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(1, 0.0)

chomp = pygame.mixer.Sound("C:/Python34/chomp.wav")
 #------BG, Screen & Caption
pygame.display.set_caption('Fishy the Turtle')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 616))
bg_img = pygame.image.load("C:/Python34/icebackground.png")
screen.blit(bg_img,(0,0))
pygame.display.flip()

 #------Image Preparation
turtle = pygame.image.load("C:/Python34/turtle.png")
fish = pygame.image.load("C:/Python34/fish.png")

 #------Movement, Coords, Collisions & Fish
turtlepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(mouse_visibility)

turtle_rect = turtle.get_rect()
fish_rect = fish.get_rect()

points = 0
fish_pos_list = []

if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[1] == True:
    while 1 == 1:
        mousepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        text = font.render("Points: %s" % points, True, (0, 128, 0))
        screen.blit(text, (0, 0))

        new_fish = random.randint(0, 6)
        fish_x = random.randint(0, 943)
        fish_y = random.randint(0, 552)

        if mousepos[1] - turtlepos[1] < 0:  
            turtlepos[1] -= turtlespeed
        else:
            turtlepos[1] += turtlespeed

        if mousepos[2] - turtlepos[2] < 0:
            turtlepos[2] -= turtlespeed
        else:
            turtlepos[2] += turtlespeed

        screen.blit(turtle_rect,(turtlepos[1],turtlepos[2]))
        pygame.display.flip()

        if new_fish == 0:
            screen.blit(fish_rect,(fish_x, fish_y)
            pygame.display.flip()
            fish_count += 1
            start_time = time.time()
            positions = {'x':fish_x, 'y':fish_y, 'fishtimer':start_time}
            fish_pos_list.append(positions)

        if time.time() - fish_pos_list[FISHTIMER OF FIRST ITEM IN LIST] >= 10:
            screen.blit(bg_img, (X OF FIRST ITEM, Y OF FIRST ITEM), pygame.Rect(X OF FIRST ITEM, Y OF FIRST ITEM, 81, 62))
            del fish_pos_list[0]

        if turtle_rect.colliderect(fish_rect):
            screen.blit(bg_img, (X OF FIRST ITEM, Y OF FIRST ITEM), pygame.Rect(X OF FIRST ITEM, Y OF FIRST ITEM, 81, 62))
            chomp.play()
            DELETE FISH FROM LIST
            points += 1

        pygame.display.update()
        mainClock.tick(40)
```

Thanks for helping me with this, hd1, but I cant say for postion in positions (I am calling positions "fish_pos_list") because i have this if statement:

```
if new_fish == 0:
            screen.blit(fish_rect,(fish_x, fish_y)
            pygame.display.flip()
            fish_count += 1
            start_time = time.time()
            positions = {'x':fish_x, 'y':fish_y, 'fishtimer':start_time}
            fish_pos_list.append(positions)
```

I have all of the dictionaries (maps) named positions, so it will be confused when i say positions, because they are *all* called positions. Again, thank you a TON for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While maps (or dictionaries) can have 2 items apiece, there's no rule saying the items themselves have to be scalar. See the following example:

```
position = {'x':1, 'y':3, 'fishcount':5}
positions = []
positions.append(position)
```

To address your comment:

```
for position in positions:
    if position['fishcount'] > 9:
        # do stuff
    else:
        # do other stuff
```

Hope that helps. If you have further problems, feel free to post a comment.

Comment: If I have a bunch of dictionaries inside of a list, and I want to see the fishcount of the first dictionary, how would I write that? Just the first dictionary of the list though, because I want to have an if statement saying "if the time (fishcount) of the first dictionary is greater than or equal to ten seconds, get rid of the fish and delete it from the list" I just dont know how to say the first part.

Comment: Kindly see my edit -- also, you should vote up accepted answers

Comment: I don't have enough rep. I would _really_ love to up your post, and I tried earlier, but I need 15 rep.

Comment: You may want to see the bottom of the original post. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, forgot to tag you. @hd1

Answer (score 0):

can you use a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html?highlight=named%20tuple#collections.namedtuple?)?

`from collections import namedtuple`

`Fish = namedtuple('Fish', 'count, x, y')`
`a_fish = Fish(fish_count, fish_x, fish_y)`

then you can access by index: `a_fish[0]` 
or access by name: `a_fish.fish_count`